# How do I deal with the Agora exception "e/agora sdk cannot open log file for writing agorartm.log err=30"?

Tags: android, agora.io, rtm

I use Agora as my RTM(Real Time Messaging) SDK, but after I set it up for Android develop, everything worked fine except for the problem that the RTMClientListener did not automatically update the messages received, and the debug console shows "e/agora sdk cannot open log file for writing agorartm.log err=30". Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you can share more information about the problem you are facing. A minimal reproducible sample can a long way in helping me solve your problem. Are you using peer-to-peer messaging or channel messaging? Regarding the log error, have you made sure to add the following permission ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />```

Comment: I am using peer to peer messaging, the detail is that I could receive and send messages properly. But the messages are only updated when I scrolled to the bottom and make contact with the screen or after dismissing the keyboard, and I also included the permissions to the external storage. Is there anything else that I can do.

Comment: The Agora SDK isn't dependant on the UI of your application so the issue should be something else. Please share a minimum reproducible sample for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The lines above allow Android application read and write permission of external files Add this into AndroidManifest.xml file - before application tag:

```
package="com.example.yourproject">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application...
```

Regarding the Agora Flutter app, the example app only works with low security mode Agora projects. Token or primary certificate activated projects won't work with the example app. Go to Agora dashboard, create a new project with low security level - only APP Id type. Then try the example app with the new App id copied from the dashboard of new project.